# Copied Project Steps Through Original Project When Debugging in Ecplise

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I copied a project within eclipse (version 3.4.2) to create a new instance of the project. Everything seems to work as expected except when I debug the project. I put a breakpoint in a file of the copied project and when it breaks, it displays the file from the original project. The debug information like variable values, etc seem to be from the new project though. I have replaced some files in the new project, so they are different.

The projects are tomcat java projects. I did change the debug config to point to the new project. All the paths I've found seem to be right, but I think I'm just missing one little part and I'm not sure what else to look at.

Any one else run into this?

Comment: Still having this issue - I have a new version of eclipse (Helios SR1) and is also happening when I check out a new version of the same source code from the repository. Mostly an annoyance now since I can use the "close" functionality, but something I still would like to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the source path and the build path of the project? Also, have a look at the classpath of the launcher you are using, it can be different from the project's build path.

If it is none of these, you can try closing the original project, then whatever in Eclipse tries to access your old project should complain. The error message should help you find the culprit.

Comment: The source path under Java Build Path is correct. Not sure about the launcher classpath. I do have the Run/Debug config set correctly (if that's what you are referring to)

Comment: As for the close project suggestion. I tried this: It steps through the correct file/project when the original project is closed but goes back to stepping through the original once I open the project again. No errors as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MacAnthony: Yes, Run/Debug is where the launchers are located.